# Get value of json response swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

This is my code:

```
do {
   if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
   print(json)
   let success = json ["success"] as? Int
   print("Success: \(success)")
```

And this is my output:

```
{
    error = "Account does not exist, please create it!";
}
Success: nil
```

`

So, before `let success = json ["success"] as? Int`, everything works well, but why is my output after this line `nil`?

This is my php:

```
public function login($username,$password) {
        $query = "Select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $json['success'] = 'Welcome '. $username . '!';
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        } else {
            $json['error'] = 'Account does not exist, please create it!';
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        }
```

Comment: I'm assuming the JSON you're parsing doesn't contain the key "success", which is why it's nil. But without seeing the JSON it's just an assumption.

Comment: Thanks, in your PHP `else` statement, you do not return a value for the key "success", and that's why it is nil.

Comment: Oh, thats right. Thank you!

Comment: i don't know why you are assigning the "success" value as Int. Because from php code it should be "string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let success = json ["success"] as? Int`

When you use this line it will extract the value of the key "success". As your json response does not contain that field it sets nil in the success variable.

Along with the error key you will need to return the success key too.

Comment: So what do I need to do?

Comment: You will need to add a success key in the else part too. Or you can add another key called "status" which will return whether the login was successful or not. If status says success they you can show the message in "success" key. If status says error then you can show the message in "error" key

Answer (score 2):

Success is `nil` because key 'success' does not exist in the JSON.

`X as? Int` = try to make x an `Int` from X when possible. If not possible (because the value is nil or the value is not convertible to an `Int`), make it `Nil`. That's what the question mark does.

So, I would do this:

```
if let success = json ["success"] as? Int {
    print("Success: \(success)")
} else {
    // Failed
}
```

You could also change your PHP code to make sure it always returns the 'success' key. However, I would recommend to use the Swift code above since you are always safe then.